# How to display the count of all items on click of a button in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have say 9 items on a carousel.

I want to show the count of individual items below the the carousel images.

I have created a Plunker for demonstrating the issue.

[Plunker Link](http://embed.plnkr.co/gOiohNabzxy8MgG4ka15/)

**HTML CODE**

```
<head>
<script data-require="angular.js@1.2.19" data-semver="1.2.19" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js">
</script>
<script data-require="jquery@2.1.1" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://vasyabigi.github.io/angular-slick/bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css" />
<script src="http://vasyabigi.github.io/angular-slick/bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.js"></script>
<script src="angular-slick.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="appController">
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
<button type="button" ng-click="showCount()">Show count of all items</button>

<slick ng-if="dataLoaded" init-onload="false" data="dataLoaded" slides-to-show="3" dots="true">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <span>
        <img ng-src="{{ item.imgSrc }}" alt="{{ item.catId}}" />
    </span>
    <span>{{ item.catId }}</span>
  </div>
</slick>
```

**JS CODE**

```
var app = angular.module("slick-example", ["slick"]);
app.controller('appController', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.items = [];
    // simulate that the data is loaded from a remote source
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.items = [{
            imgSrc: 'http://placekitten.com/325/325',
            catId: '1'
        }, {
            imgSrc: 'http://placekitten.com/g/325/325',
            catId: '2'
        }, {
            imgSrc: 'http://placekitten.com/325/325',
            catId: '3'
        }, {
            imgSrc: 'http://placekitten.com/g/325/325',
            catId: '4'
        }, {
            imgSrc: 'http://placekitten.com/325/325',
            catId: '5'
        }, {
            imgSrc: 'http://placekitten.com/g/325/325',
            catId: '6'
        }, {
            imgSrc: 'http://placekitten.com/325/325',
            catId: '7'
        }, {
            imgSrc: 'http://placekitten.com/g/325/325',
            catId: '8'
        }, {
            imgSrc: 'http://placekitten.com/325/325',
            catId: '9'
        }];
        $scope.countItem = [{
            "catId": 1,
            "availableCount": 2
        }, {
            "catId": 2,
            "availableCount": 3
        }, {
            "catId": 3,
            "availableCount": 4
        }, {
            "catId": 4,
            "availableCount": 2
        }, {
            "catId": 5,
            "availableCount": 1
        }, {
            "catId": 6,
            "availableCount": 5
        }, {
            "catId": 7,
            "availableCount": 3
        }, {
            "catId": 8,
            "availableCount": 2
        }, {
            "catId": 9,
            "availableCount": 1
        }];
        // update the dataLoaded flag after the data has been loaded
        // i dont know why but its important that the flag doesnt get initialized in an previous step like $scope.dataLoaded = false;
        $scope.dataLoaded = true;
    }, 2000);
    $scope.showCount = function() {}
});
```

When the button (button - Show count of individual items) is clicked I am trying to show the count of individual items below each image in carousel but I am not able to find a way to do so. On the click of the button count of all items is to be shown

Please refer the Plunker ( I am only using AngularJS and vanilla JS ,no Jquery )

Please help me how to show the count of individual items of the carousel just below each image

Comment: you want to relation the countItem with items ?

Comment: @ Jesus Carrasco yes count or quantity - any of the 2 terms you prefer? But I have to show the count/quantity in a div below the images of the carousel at the same time

Comment: @Jesus Carrasco i have to show the count of individual items , say count of item 1 is 2 while item 2 count is 4 , i have to show this individual count thing below each image

Comment: ok i understant you need to mix both json according the catId

Comment: @Jesus Carrasco I don't want to mix the json . Is it possible to leave the 
 2 json intact?

Comment: @zv321, I've created a version that does not modify the arrays (json). I recommend that you at that as a parameter to your requirements in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways, second based on comment info.

### Version not modifying array

This version waits until the data has "loaded", and then will create a map that will be used in the interpolated values of the count in your HTML.

#### HTML

This button will toggle the count on/off:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="showCount = !showCount">Toggle Count</button>
```

This goes where you want to display the count within the `ng-repeat`:

```
<span ng-if="showCount">Count of Items: {{ countMap[$index] }}</span>
```

For more on `$index`, review documentation on [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat). Basically, it's telling you the index (location) in the array that the current repeated element is sourced from.

#### JS

In the root of your controller:

```
  // Create a mapping of array position : count
  $scope.countMap = {};
```

This allows us to look up data later with ease. Ex:

$scope.countMap[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) = 'hello';
console.log($scope.countMap[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)); // -> hello

Then, after your $timeout, once it has resolved (meaning timeout is reached, http request finished, etc):

```
$timeout(function() {
   // Abbreviated, not including items.

  }, 2000).then(function() {
    // After resolve, assuming you are calling an API in real implementation

    // Iterate through the returned items, and add the count
    // to the array pos : count mapping
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
      $scope.countMap[i] = getCountFor($scope.items[i].catId);
    }

  });
```

** Also of note **, you set `$scope.dataLoaded = true`, but it is within the timeout. It should move into the `.then(function() {}` to ensure it's not set until the promise has resolved.

And then, the original getCountFor(id) function from the modifying version below:

```
  function getCountFor(id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.countItem.length; i++) {
      if ($scope.countItem[i].catId == id) {
        return $scope.countItem[i].availableCount;
      }
    }
  }
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/UOY7WONh6TUCBRrZYnvZ?p=preview

### Version modifying array

This should do the trick. When you click "show count...", the function will iterate over each cat object in $scope.items, and call `getCountFor(id)` and append the availableCount value as found via relating the catId for the objects in each array.

#### HTML

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <span>
        <img ng-src="{{ item.imgSrc }}" alt="{{ item.catId}}" />
    </span>
    <span>{{ item.catId }}</span>
    <span> Count of Items: {{ item.availableCount }}</span>
  </div>
```

#### JS

This is a function used to separate the concerns of the code. It takes `id` as a parameter. It then increments `i`, starting at 0, and going until the value of `i` is the length of the `$scope.countItem` array. For each position in the array, there is an item. If the value of `id` passed to the function matches the value of `catId` for the object at position `i` of the array, the value of available count is returned.

```
  function getCountFor(id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.countItem.length; i++) {
      if ($scope.countItem[i].catId == id) {
        return $scope.countItem[i].availableCount;
      }
    }
  }
```

This function is on `$scope` as it is called from your UI. When called, it iterates over each item in `$scope.items`, and sets a new property called `availableCount` on that item. It will render each item in `$scope.items` to look like this:

```
{
    imgSrc: 'http://placekitten.com/325/325',
    catId: '1',
    availableCount: 0
}
```

And the actual showCount() function:

```
  $scope.showCount = function() {
    $scope.items.forEach(function(item) {
      item.availableCount = getCountFor(item.catId);
    })
  }
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/2uLdLgVtsjbT6v4R0DWi?p=preview

Comment: i have to show the count of individual items , say count of item 1 is 2 while item 2 count is 4 , i have to show this thing below each item

Comment: its working. can you please help me understand your JS code. I am just a beginner programmer

Comment: but i don't want to merge the 2 json

Comment: I've created a new version that does not modify the array, and uses a dictionary instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can prepare an array like this on click:

```
 $scope.showCount = function(){

  angular.forEach($scope.countItem,function(val,key){
    $scope.count[val.catId] = val.availableCount;
  });

}
```

[working plunkar link](https://plnkr.co/edit/fjoSWSkVH8smsVUTvQJs?p=preview)

Comment: i have to show the count of individual items , say count of item 1 is 2 while item 2 count is 4 , i have to show this thing

Comment: @Brian thanx :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the items to find the idCat wich is in the other array. and sub-loop, to find the match id, and obtain the availableCount.

You need to do this in the showCount function

**HTML**
    Show count of all items

```
<slick ng-if="dataLoaded" init-onload="false" data="dataLoaded" slides-to-show="3" dots="true">
  <div ng-repeat="item in itemsCopy">
    <span>
        <img ng-src="{{ item.imgSrc }}" alt="{{ item.catId}}" />
    </span>
    <span>{{ item.catId }} {{ 'count: '+ item.availableCount }}</span>
  </div>
</slick>
```

**controller**

```
$scope.showCount = function(){

 $scope.itemsCopy = $scope.item;

angular.forEach($scope.itemsCopy, function(value, index){

    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.countItem.length; i++){
      console.log(value, $scope.countItem[i].catId);
      if(parseInt(value.catId) === $scope.countItem[i].catId ){
        value.availableCount = $scope.countItem[i].availableCount
      } 
    }
});
console.log($scope.itemsCopy);
};
```

WHEN click the button asid the count will show the count.

i put a plknr with the example:
[sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/7xVzJhZtXtnj4PNpTOrJ?p=preview)

Comment: its working. can you please help me understand your JS code. I am just a beginner programmer

Comment: have you merged the 2 json ? I want to keep the 2 json intact , I don't want to merge them

Comment: they dont merge only add the attribute availableCont to items. instead of that you can make a copy for items. and in the ng-repeat do for the copy.

Comment: I can't get your last statement. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: I can't get your last statement. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: yo can make a copy of item array, over the copy aply the foreach, and in the html you ng-rpeat from the copy, and thats not merge your original item with countItem.